# how to find the value of x from the word equation of linear equation in two variable

Tags: linear-algebra

i was doing the the sum of `NCERT- Exampler` page 28, question no. 21

The question is:

> In a competitive examination, one mark is awarded for each correct
>   answer  while 1/2 is deducted for every wrong answer. Jayanti answered
>   120 question and got 90 marks. How many question did she answered
>   correctly

its answer is `100` question

from this question i made one equation:

```
x - y/2 = 90
```

where `x` is the total number of correct answers and `y` is the total number of wrong answer

(also i am going to solve this with elimination method)

and now i couldn't find the second equation...

please help me! 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Total questions answered$=120$
Correct answers$=x$
So, Incorrect answers$=120-x$

So, your second equation is actually $x+y=120$

Comment: @anni sure...you will get your desired answer.

Comment: @anni you are most welcome...